# ioperm is working without root permission

Tags: c, linux, io, x86

I read that we need superuser permission to access I/O ports from user space. But i am saying different behavior. ioperm is successful under normal user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/io.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (!ioperm(0x70, 3, 1)) {
        perror("ioperm failed");
    }
    else {
        printf("ioperm on 0x70 success\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

$ ./prog 
ioperm on 0x70 success
```

Is this the expected behavior

Comment: Use `strace` to decode system calls; that sanity-check would have shown you that `ioperm` was returning `-EPERM`.  Voted to close as off-topic: typo / not a real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioperm.2.html#RETURN_VALUE):

> On success, zero is returned.  On error, -1 is returned, and  errno  is set appropriately.

You have this backwards. -1 means failure, but your code incorrectly assumes it means success.